# drop database hangs with "Waiting for table metadata lock" in MySQL8 RDS on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

We have a large table in a database that a user tried to run `DELETE * FROM table` on. It was still running the next day so we killed the process.

I tried renaming, dropping and truncating the affected table, and even the whole database but any query ends up `Waiting for table metadata lock`. I can query from the table though.

All info I can find suggests there will be a process somewhere that is still going, but I've rebooted the server and the issue persists.

It's a staging server with multiple other databases so it's reasonably busy, but I don't see problems elsewhere and I can add and drop other databases. It's just this one database that seems to have the problem.

After [enabling the performance schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.EnableMySQL.html) I see some entries in `performance_schema.metadata_locks` table like the following:

[image: table of metadata_locks]

I'm not sure what the `dictionary_impl.cc:434` refers to but I don't see anything in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` relating to this.

The tables referenced in the locks table are all from the database I'm trying to drop.

Comment: truncate the tables before dropping them

Comment: Updated the question, it's now not possible to truncate the table

Comment: restart the ec2 from the panel, somthing is iin a deadlock

Comment: Have you checked: `select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks;`? That PS view should be enabled by default on MySQL 8, but if it isn't, that's an issue for AWS support to answer.

Comment: I've enabled the performance_schema now, but not sure how to interpret the results…